# How to get JSON values from jquery

Tags: json

i got this json object from a query in php:

```
[
    [{
        "id": "21",
        "city": "Bogota",
        "eps": "PUESTO DE SALUD CHINITA",
        "sem1": "0",
        "sem2": "0",
        "sem3": "0"
    }, {
        "id": "22",
        "city": "Medellin",
        "eps": "PUESTO DE SALUD DE MEDALLO",
        "sem1": "0",
        "sem2": "0",
        "sem3": "0"
    }, {
        "id": "23",
        "city": "Cali",
        "eps": "PUESTO DE SALUD DE CALI",
        "sem1": "0",
        "sem2": "0",
        "sem3": "0"
    }]
]
```

and i have this code in jquery:

```
$.ajax(

    {
      url: 'consultar_tabla.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: {},

            success: function(result)

            { 


                  $.each(result, function(i,item)
                  {

                    alert(result[i].city);

                  });


            } //end success ajax

    });//end ajax
```

but it shows **undefined**

Whats is the correct way of show each value?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your JSON is an array of arrays (with only one array in it), so you want something like this:

```
$.each(result[0], ...
```